# Azure CLI ProvisioningState : Failed

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I am trying azure group command using cli. its giving me error:

```
error:   Deployment provisioning state was not successful
```

Below is the command i am using:

```
azure group deployment create -g "Default" --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reshmai/azure/master/testmitheshgithubdb.json
```

For more info : When i tried with different uri with not given serverName. Its successfully created, but with serverName its not getting created, error is throwing.